# Node js - function to return array of data read from database

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to create a function in node js which reads database values in a for loop and pushes them into an array, and then at the end returns this array.
My functions looks like this at the moment:

```
function loadTokens(userIds) {
    var tokens = [];
    userIds.forEach(item => {
        admin.database().ref('/users/' + item).once('value').then(snapShot => {
            var user = snapShot.val();
            console.log('User', user.name);
            console.log('token', user.fcmToken);
            return tokens.push(user.fcmToken);
        };
    });
    return tokens;
}
```

In the main part of the code I would like to call this funtion and use a .then to get the returned array and call another funtion which takes the array as a parameter. I would like to do this to ensure that the array is filled when passed as a parameter.

```
return loadTokens(userIds).then(tokens => {
    console.log('tokens', tokens)
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
});
```

I did some research and I learned that I would have to return a Promise in my function which somehow contains the array so it can be used in a .then statement.

Can you help me out how I can return a promise in the function and how will the array be accessible in the .then part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
function loadTokens(userIds) {
    var promises = userIds.map(item => admin.database().ref('/users/' + item).once('value'));
    return Promise.all(promises).then(snapshots => {
        return snapshots.map(snapshot => snapshot.val().fcmToken);
    });
}
```

So we're using `Promise.all()` to wait for all tokens to be loaded, and return the token from our `then` completion handler.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply Frank! Do I undestand correctly that this function returns an array of `Promise` and in the `then` in the main part I have a result of promises, each containing an fcmToken?
In this case how can I access the array of fcmTokens outside the function?
Sorry, I'm very new to JavaScript and Node.js...

Comment: I didn't test the code, but it should pass an array of tokens to the `then()` callback.

Comment: I gave it a go but got the following error:
ReferenceError: snapShot is not defined at Promise.all.then.snapshots                                                               
Do I need to access `snapShot` from `snapshots` smohehow?

Comment: Ah, I forgot to add a loop. Added that now.

Comment: Thanks for the update, it's working perfectly now. :)